# Component not rerendering after axios Get (React)

Tags: reactjs, axios, state-management

I'm trying to render List of items of my DB using React.Context.
All my request work pretty well.
when i console log my states first I get an empty array and then array with the data that I need but my component is not updating. I have to go to another page an then go back to this page to get the data. I don't really understand why... here are my files..

**ArticlesContext.js :**

```
    import React, { useState, createContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
export const ArticlesContext = createContext();

export function ArticlesProvider(props) {
    const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);
    const [user, setUser] =useState(0)

    async function getArticles () {
        await axios.get(`/api/publicItem`)
        .then(res => {
            setArticles(res.data);
        })
    }
    
    useEffect( () => {
     getArticles()
    }, [user])
    
    console.log(articles);
    
    return (
        <ArticlesContext.Provider value={[articles, setArticles]}>
            {props.children}
        </ArticlesContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

**Inventaire.js :**

```
    import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    
    import './Inventaire.css';
    
    import { ArticlesContext } from '../../../context/ArticlesContext';
    import DeleteAlert from './Delete/Delete';
    import Modify from './Modify/Modify';
    import Filter from './Filter/Filter';
    import axios from 'axios'
    import Crud from '../../Elements/Articles/Crud/Crud';
import List from './List/List';
    
    export default function Inventaire() {
        const [articles, setArticles] = useContext(ArticlesContext);
        const [filter, setFilter] = useState(articles)
        console.log(articles);
        //list for Inputs
        const cat = articles.map(a => a.category.toLowerCase());
        const categoryFilter = ([...new Set(cat)]);
        const gender = articles.map(a => a.gender.toLowerCase());
        const genderFilter = ([...new Set(gender)]);
        //Event Listenner
    
        //Uncheck All checkboxes
        function UncheckAll() {
            const el = document.querySelectorAll("input.checkboxFilter");
            console.log(el);
            for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
                var check = el[i];
                if (!check.disabled) {
                    check.checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
    
        //SearchBar
        const searchChange = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
    
            const stuff = articles.filter((i) => {
                return i.name.toLowerCase().match(e.target.value.toLowerCase())
            })
            setFilter(stuff)
            UncheckAll(true)
        }
    
    
        const Types = (e) => {
            if (e.target.checked === true) {
                const stuff = filter.filter((i) => {
                    return i.category.toLowerCase().match(e.target.value.toLowerCase())
                })
                setFilter(stuff)
                console.log(articles);
            } else if (e.target.checked === false) {
                setFilter(articles)
            }
        }
        const Gender = (e) => {
            if (e.target.checked === true) {
                const stuff = filter.filter((i) => {
                    console.log(i.category, e.target.value);
                    return i.gender.toLowerCase().match(e.target.value.toLowerCase())
                })
                setFilter(stuff)
            } else if (e.target.checked === false) {
                setFilter(articles)
            }
        }
        return (
            <div className="inventaireContainer">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Recherche un Article" onChange={searchChange} />
    
                <div className="inventaireMenu">
                    <Crud />
                    <Filter
                        filter={Types}
                        categorys={categoryFilter}
                        genre={genderFilter}
                        target={Gender}
                    />
                </div>
    
                <List filter={filter} articles={articles}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

**List.js :**

```
import React from 'react';
import DeleteAlert from '../Delete/Delete';
import Modify from '../Modify/Modify';

export default function List({ filter, articles }) {
    return (
        <div>
            {filter.map((details, i) => {
                return (
                    <div className="inventaireBlock" >
                        <div className="inventaireGrid">
                            <div className="inventaireItemImg">
                                <img src={details.image} alt="ItemImg" />
                            </div>
                            <h2>{details.name}</h2>
                            <h3>{details.category}</h3>
                            <h3>{details.gender}</h3>
                            <div>
                                <p>S :{details.sizes[0].s}</p>
                                <p>M :{details.sizes[0].m}</p>
                                <p>L :{details.sizes[0].l}</p>
                                <p>XL :{details.sizes[0].xl}</p>
                            </div>
                            <h2> Prix: {details.price}</h2>
                            <div className="modify">
                                <Modify details={details._id} />
                            </div>
                            <div className="delete"  >
                                <DeleteAlert details={details._id} articles={articles} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: With your current code, it should work. Here the [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-i5hntz?file=src%2Fcontexts%2FArticlesContext.js) mimicking your code. It immediate display the data once you entered the page

Comment: Btw, from which component did you pass `filter` & `articles` to `List` component?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I pass it by **Inventaire** Component. I should probably setUser to 1 in my context or make my axios get req in the component idk...

Comment: At which part or line of code that you called `List` component from `Inventaire` component?

Comment: I change `<Filter/>` (line 85) Component name into `<List/>` that was an error of myself. But I think the error is coming from the filter state. It is undefined when page loading so nothing to show but when I trigger **searchChange ** all content showing up. I will start from here to solve the issue

Comment: can you make the edit on your code above

Comment: So I assume the error still persist even after you do `<List filter={filter} articles={articles}/>` instead of just `<List filter={filter}/>` like what you currently have in your `Inventaire` component right now right?

Comment: Ok I solved It by using `If Else` in my list component taking **filter** and **articles** as parameters

Comment: Nice!. Glad you able to work that out.